# Remove numbers from ArrayList of Strings

Tags: java, arraylist

I have ArrayList of Strings and I want to remove numbers from it. How Can achieve it?

```java
ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList();

arraylist.add("01 Hello 88");
arraylist.add("02 World 88");
```

For example I just want to remove 01 and 02 .. and rest can be same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question.  Here it is:

```
UnaryOperator<List<String>> trimHeader = (inList) -> {
    List<String> outList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s : inList) {
        String[] elements = s.split(" ");
        outList.add(Arrays.stream(elements).skip(1).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
    }
    return outList;
};

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("01 Hello 88");
list.add("02 World 88");
trimHeader.apply(list).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

Hello 88
World 88

Notice that the Lambda function brings no side-effect to the original list.

[Edit]
Updated a variable name above.
In addition, consider the function provided in this reply for a more general purpose usage -- it removes the first element based on checking the space.  The first element can be a number or some characters.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want subString only since you want to remove only `01` not `88` then you can use `substring()`

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
  arraylist.set(i, arraylist.get(i).substring(3));
}
```

Or You can use Stream API

```
List<String> arraylist = new ArrayList();
arraylist.add("01 Hello 88");
arraylist.add("02 World 88");
arraylist = arraylist.stream().map(a -> a.substring(3)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to remove leading digits followed by spaces, is to use a regular expression to match that, and then replace it with an empty string.

The regex would be `^\d+\s+`, which as a Java string literal would be `"^\\d+\\s+"`.

To update all values in a list in Java 8+, you can do it using the [`replaceAll(UnaryOperator<E> operator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) method, like this:

```java
ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
arraylist.add("01 Hello 88");
arraylist.add("02 World 88");

arraylist.replaceAll(s -> s.replaceFirst("^\\d+\\s+", ""));

System.out.println(arraylist);
```

*Output*

```
[Hello 88, World 88]
```